# How to replace a string within a larger string but exclude anything within img tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace

I have created a system where i load out content from a Database field into a literal as content for an article. I have added the ability to pass a search text string via the URL to be highlighted on the page. So this is being done via doing a replace like so below...

```
articleTitle = articleTitle.Replace(searchString, "<span title=\"Searched Term Match\" class=\"SearchedTextTitle\">" + searchString + "</span>");
```

The issue i have encountered is my content is all HTML so it includes the html for images and so on and if the alt tags or image url's contain the search text term it is also being replaced by the replace method above. How can i exclude any of the content that is within HTML tags etc?

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: I recommend that you use a HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use IndexOf("") method to build substrings and perform the replaces on only the parts of the HTML you want to affect, or you can use regex replace, which will allow you to build more logic into your search.